# How to list all branches in SVN

Tags: svn

How I can list all branches in SVN repo which are nested deeply. I tried

> svn ls %svn-url-to-branch-folder%

But it gives list of files and folders as well.

I have following branch structure in my SVN repo

- /branches/branch-a
- /branches/branch-a/branch-b
- /branches/branch-a/branch-c
- /branches/branch-a/branch-c/branch-d
- /branches/branch-e
- /branches/branch-f

So I need to get branch list with path (Not files/folder inside branches) e.g.

- /branches/branch-a
- /branches/branch-a/branch-b
- /branches/branch-a/branch-c
- /branches/branch-a/branch-c/branch-d
- /branches/branch-e
- /branches/branch-f

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the --depth option

```
svn ls http://snvServer/Project/branches/ --depth immediates
```

[From subversion docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html)

> --depth **empty**:
>   Include only the immediate target of the operation, not any of its file or directory children.
>
> --depth **files**:
>   Include the immediate target of the operation and any of its immediate file children.
>
> --depth ***immediates***:
>   Include the immediate target of the operation and any of its immediate file or directory children. The directory children will themselves be empty.
>
> --depth **infinity**:
>   Include the immediate target, its file and directory children, its children's children, and so on to full recursion.